# How do we know if we are in a local or global minimum when using gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have been learning about Real Analysis and recently undergone a stats module on regressions etc.. We have come across gradient descent and I was curious about, if we have a complicated loss function, whether we can tell if we are in a local minimum or at the global minimum?

Comment: In no way. You won't know.

Comment: You either a. Prove some numerical properties of the objective function that guarantees it, or b. Exhaustively evaluate the objective function at all possible values.

Comment: Are you asking this question from a theoretical or a practical perspective? In practice, one determines unimodality by running local optimizers with many random initializations. If they all converge to the same optimum, we take this as evidence that the loss is unimodal (though of course we could be wrong). If they converge to different optima, this is a certificate of multimodality (assuming convergence was correctly assessed). Theoretically, we usually only expect global optimality for a special class of well-behaved unimodal functions called *convex functions*.

Comment: @JohnMadden: do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @StephanKolassa if OP can provide just a little more guidance on what aspects of the problem they're interested in I'd be happy to :)

Comment: btw I highly recommend anyone asking themselves questions similar to the OP's to read the introduction of Nesterov's intro optimization book (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-8853-9) which free online and starts by discussing the impossibility of optimization in the case of a general function.